# EFPosh function doesnt work with variables

Tags: powershell

im trying to automate some jira issue creation with powershell, and im saving all the issues into a msql db aswell. I have created the following function, which seems to work when i call it with strings. but when i even try to call it with variabels it throws an exception. why?

```
Import-Module EFPosh

function Create-OrSkip-DBEntry {
    param (
        [string]$AcuityId,
        [string]$Name,
        [string]$DatumZeit,
        [string]$Typ,
        [string]$PersoStandort,
        [string]$Bemerkung,
        [string]$Gerätgrösse,
        [string]$istErsatzgerät,
        [string]$istStorniert
    )
    class PersoTermine {
        [System.String]$AcuityId
        [System.String]$Name
        [System.String]$DatumZeit
        [System.String]$Typ
        [System.String]$PersoStandort
        [System.String]$Bemerkung
        [System.String]$Gerätgrösse
        [System.String]$istErsatzgerät
        [System.String]$istStorniert
    }
    $Tables = @(
        (New-EFPoshEntityDefinition -Type "PersoTermine" -Schema "dbo" -PrimaryKey 'AcuityId')
    )
    $SQLiteConnectionString = "Server=x; Database=x; User Id=x; Password=x;"
    try {
        $Context = New-EFPoshContext -ConnectionString $SQLiteConnectionString -DBType 'MSSQL' -Entities $Tables
        if ($Context -eq $null) {
            throw "Failed to create the database context."
        }
        # Check if an entry with the same AcuityId already exists
        $ExistingEntry = Search-EFPosh -DbContext $Context -Entity PersoTermine -Expression { $_.AcuityId -eq $AcuityId }
        if ($ExistingEntry -eq $null) {
            # If the entry does not exist, create a new one
            $NewObject = [PersoTermine]::new()
            $NewObject.AcuityId = $AcuityId
            $NewObject.Name = $Name
            $NewObject.DatumZeit = $DatumZeit
            $NewObject.Typ = $Typ
            $NewObject.PersoStandort = $PersoStandort
            $NewObject.Bemerkung = $Bemerkung
            $NewObject.Gerätgrösse = $Gerätgrösse
            $NewObject.istErsatzgerät = $istErsatzgerät
            $NewObject.istStorniert = $istStorniert

            Add-EFPoshEntity -Entity $NewObject -DbContext  $Context -SaveChanges

            Write-Host "New entry created with AcuityId '$AcuityId'."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Entry with AcuityId '$AcuityId' already exists. No new entry created."
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
}
```

```
$id = "testId"
Create-OrSkip-DBEntry -AcuityId "id1" -Name "TestEntry" -DatumZeit "Datum" -Typ "Typ" -PersoStandort "Standort" -Bemerkung "Bemerkung" -Gerätgrösse "Größe" -istErsatzgerät "Ja" -istStorniert "Nein"
Create-OrSkip-DBEntry -AcuityId $id  -Name "TestEntry" -DatumZeit "Datum" -Typ "Typ" -PersoStandort "Standort" -Bemerkung "Bemerkung" -Gerätgrösse "Größe" -istErsatzgerät "Ja" -istStorniert "Nein"
```

```
Error: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Add" mit 1 Argument(en):  "The entity type 'PersoTermine' was not found. Ensure tha
t the entity type has been added to the model."
Entry with AcuityId 'id1' exists, but no updates were needed.
```